# Superconductivity: how does the critical temperature depend on the pressure?

Tags: pressure, superconductivity

This question is inspired by a [recent publication](http://www.nature.com/news/superconductivity-record-sparks-wave-of-follow-up-physics-1.18191), in which researchers managed to boost the record critical temperature at which a substance becomes superconducting by applying an enormous pressure to the sample.

Is there an easy way to understand that increasing the pressure increases the temperature at which the substance becomes superconducting? We know the equation for the critical temperature from BCS theory:

$$
k_B T_c \sim E_D e^{-1/D(\epsilon_F) V},
$$
($E_D$ Debye cutoff energy; $D(\epsilon_F)$ the density of states at the fermi energy and $V$ the electron-phonon coupling). It is not clear to me how the pressure influences this equation. Is it directly via the electron-phonon coupling?

Comment: I would say that external pressure modifies phonon modes, thus changing the electron-phonon intercation, but this is just a guess

Comment: By changing the inter-atomic spacing, pressure can vary the entire band structure. This can be seen clearly from the fact that there are many examples of pressure-induced solid phase changes (i.e. the bcc-hcp transition of Fe with a bcc-hcp-fcc tripe point at 757K and 10.4GPa). Changes in the phonon spectrum are, of course, reflective of the overall change in inter-atomic potential under pressure.